# python and ctypes, ctypes returns the wrong float values from nested struct

Tags: python, c, struct, ctypes

I have a struct called DetectorResult, which has another structure called detector_predictions_t inside it. That nested structure is a pointer to a structure, not the value of a structure:

```
/// detector result structures
typedef struct _detector_predictions_t {
    float x1;
    float x2;
    float y1;
    float y2;
    float score;
} detector_predictions_t, *pdetector_predictions_t;

typedef struct _DetectorResult {
    int detect_num;
    int class_idx;
    pdetector_predictions_t preds; ///< all face detector predictions
} DetectorResult, *pDetectorResult;
```

I have python ctypes code which correctly defines the c structures above:

```
# prediction structs
class CDetectorPredictionsT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x1", ctypes.c_float), ("x2", ctypes.c_float), ("y1", ctypes.c_float), ("y2", ctypes.c_float), ("score", ctypes.c_float)]

class CDetectorResult(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("detect_num", ctypes.c_int), ("class_idx", ctypes.c_int), ("preds", ctypes.POINTER(CDetectorPredictionsT))]
```

I have a function which returns a pointer to the DetectorResult struct:

```
pDetectorResult p_model_getresult(uint8_t* data)
{
    printf("entering\n");
    //pDetectorResult resultData = (pDetectorResult)malloc(sizeof(*resultData));
    //resultData->preds = (pdetector_predictions_t)malloc(sizeof(*resultData->preds));
    pDetectorResult resultData = (pDetectorResult)calloc(1, sizeof(*resultData));
    resultData->preds = (pdetector_predictions_t)calloc(1, sizeof(*resultData->preds));
    if(resultData == NULL) {
        printf("resultdata malloc failed");
    } else if(resultData->preds == NULL) {
        printf("preds malloc failed");
    } else {
        printf("about to memset");
        //memset(resultData, 0, sizeof(*resultData));
        printf("memset 2");
        //memset(resultData->preds, 0, sizeof(*resultData->preds));
        printf("finished memset");
        printf("successfully made det result\n");
        model_getresult(resultData, data);
        printf("the first bb is %f %f %f %f %f\n", resultData->preds->x1, resultData->preds->x2, resultData->preds->y1, resultData->preds->y2, resultData->preds->score);
        printf("returning now\n");
    }
    return resultData;
}
```

and I have python code which calls this function:

```
self.aml_lib.p_model_getresult.argtypes = [c_uint_p_type(self.width * self.height * self.channel)]
self.aml_lib.p_model_getresult.restype = ctypes.POINTER(CDetectorResult)

# ...

    def model_getresult(self, data, format):
        input_data = self.model_setinput(data, format)
        print("data s ", input_data[0], input_data[1], input_data[2])
        return self.aml_lib.p_model_getresult(input_data)
```

Lastly I have python code to inspect the results:

```
    ret = aml_object.model_getresult(data, PIXEL_FORMAT).contents
    a = ret.preds.contents.x1
```

where ret is the DetectorResult struct directly from c.

the value of a is some random number such as 1.25^25. When I print the value in c (for example printf("%f", resultData->preds->x1) ) the result is different, a number between 0 and 1.

how do I get the value of a to be the same as the value printed in printf in c?

I'm running this on linux.

Comment: The Python ctypes fields for `DetectorResult` don't seem to match the C code:  Where the C code defines `float trying; int class_idx;`, the Python code has `class_name` as a `char` array.

Comment: @TomKarzes thanks for the error. That was a typo in the question rather than in the code. I edited the question to reflect a more accurate depiction.

Comment: You should create a *REPREX* (*MCVE*) by populating the structs with dummy values from *C*. How do you print the *float*s from *Python*? What is "*1.25^25*"?